# Visual Basic Excel Conditional Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Hey so heres what I have going on.  I'm tracking due dates in a system and they are part of a spread sheet.  I have it flag yellow if it's 60 days out red if its over due (conditional formatting within the sheet) I then have a count set up 
    =COUNTIF(I3:I02, ">=" &TODAY()+60)     After Today
    =COUNTIF(I3:I102, "<=" &TODAY())       Past Due

I use these counts to indicate whether something has flagged or not then push them into the formula below.  What I'm trying to do now is actually to get the Tab of the sheet to change color based on whether something is almost due or over due in the sheet this is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is > 0
            Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is > 0
           Me.Tab.Color = vbYellow
        End Select
    Else
        Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End Sub
```

This works as far as changing the color of the tab goes but If I change the value of B2 after the fact it removes the Red flag?  I.e. one overrides the other.  I need it to stay red if there is a red one.  Basically I want it to stop if the if statement is true, if it's not proceed to checking the value of b2..etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to want to do is check the values of B1 and B2 if either B1 or B2 is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B1").Value > 0 Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf Range("B2").Value > 0 Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End Sub
```

Based on your question, it sounds like B1 and B2 contain formulas.  As such, they won't fire the `Worksheet_Change` event when they calculate a different number.  Therefore I have not included any test for the location of `Target` - the code will execute whenever **any** cell on the sheet is (manually) changed.